# WorkFlow designer fails to load in VS 2013

Tags: workflow

We are using Work Flow's in our project and it is developed in VS 2010. Recently we migrated to VS 2013 Professional. Now when we try to open a Work Flow Activity in VS 2013, we get the following error message:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'"

We could find the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions.dll" under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\WorkflowDesigner", but still when we open the WF designer, we get the FileNotFound exception.

When we close and open the WF again, we get the below error message :

System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.EditorPane.set_FileName(String value)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.EditorPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load(String fileName, UInt32 formatMode, Int32 readOnly)

Any idea what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 4):

The exception is related to missing Workflow Manager or Workflow Manager Tools on the machine which might not have installed successfully with VS installation at first.

However, you can fix this issue by installing/reinstalling them and dependencies. You might need to restart the machine as well.

Here is the link to download the installers separately: http://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=35375

Comment: This worked for me, or rather, I just went into the Web Platform Installer 5.0 and installed "Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 Refresh". Now the designer works properly in Visual Studio 2013 again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we got the root cause now. There were some internet restrictions imposed on the PC's when VS 2013 was installed for which some of the WF related stuffs didn't get downloaded/updated properly.

We tried to re-install VS 2013 without Internet restrictions, and things started to work fine. 
Hope this helps someone in need. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: my workflow was referencing a custom activity I did not have in the /bin folder. Once I placed that custom activity (.dll) into the bin folder, I had no problems.